# Need to deploy MS Access DB

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, connection-string

I have a requirement for which I have to use MS Access as database(backend) and C# windows app as frontend. I need to deploy this application on multiuser connected on LAN.
So the DB is on central sever and the app installed on indivdual machines.
I tried using System DSN to connect the MS Access DB but could not.
Please someone help with connectionstring.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Comment: See http://connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you couldn't connect to the database, but the simplest way is to use the OleDb provider for Jet (assuming of course that you have Jet installed on the client machines)

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

//
// Code ...
//

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\MyServer\Mydb.mdb");
conn.open();

//
// Use connection ...
//
```

Comment: Or ACE for 2007 and 2010 versions.

Comment: Actually I cannot connect to DB as I connot find SystemDSN on server on any workgroup machines. Also I am using ODBC for using SystemDSN

Comment: It gives me error as "[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] general error Unable to open registry key Temporary Ace DSN for process".

Comment: @kanayabhattad - Have you tried a File DSN (rather than System DSN) on the server?

Comment: Yes, I tried using File DSN, but as multiple user will use the database I prefer System DSN.

Comment: If you use the code provided in this answer, you don't need a DSN on any machine at all. Creating an `OleDBConnection` with the connection string provided here works without a DSN.

Comment: @kanayabhattad - System DSNs are for multiple user accounts on the server. I don't see how you can have *network* users use system DSNs since they are configured in the server's registry.