# How to attach MS Access databse file with c# application while deploying on user machine using Install Shield installer?

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, installshield

I am developing a c# application as **College Admission System** for some user. User will have to manage records in **MS Access databse file attached to c# application**. Now i am making an **installer** for my application in order to install it on user's machine. Solutions i have gone through is:
[Need to deploy MS Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736357/need-to-deploy-ms-access-db)

What i want is that as the application gets installed on user's computer, MS Access database file also should get attached to application. What should i need to do? Is there any beginners approach to that or any guide for this purpose?

**UPDATED**
I have created database file manually and put that file in bin folder right now (and want the same for the user). I just want somehow to get it attached to my application on user's machine, so whenever user will manage records, so records should be added/edited/updated/deleted smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Have your installer create \ write the database file to a specified directory on the target machine (e.g. AppDataFolder).

When your application starts, test this directory for the presence of the Access database file. If found, create your connection string (see ConnectionStrings.com for help). Consider storing the ConnectionString as a property of your application once you've created it so you don't have to run the same code upon startup next time.

If the Access database file is not located in the directory your installer is supposed to write it to (or your ConnectionString fails) consider prompting the user to locate the file for you (via OpenFileDialog or similar).

Note that it probably isn't a good idea to have your installer write the database file to the Program Files directory since the end user will need to be able to modify the database (and on Vista + this can be problematic due to UAC & permissions).

Comment: +1. Program Files is not write-accessible to ordinary users.  OP's case is exactly what the AppData folder is for.

Comment: Actually, ic ouldn't get very first line of your answer. Please explain that? Well end user would be suing Windows 7 and right now my databse file is in bin folder of my application and i want it to be there at user machine as well. But now i see that when shortcut will be created at user machine then how will my database file would respond?

Comment: Your installer should not write the access database to the InstallDirectory because the directory on Windows Vista and above will be write protected. Instead, you should install the database file to the AppData folder. In your C# application do not assume the database is in the bin folder or Application Directory; instead, look for it in the AppData folder.

Comment: The shortcut launches your application, not the database, correct? The shortcut should not have anything to do with nor care about the location of the database file. You will need to change your application code to not assume the database is in the same directory as the application executable.

Comment: Ok so should i let my database file be in bin folder right now? I mean to say that would Install shield automatically keep my database file to AppDataFolder?

Comment: I haven't used InstallShield in ages, but I would be surprised if it deployed it to AppData by default. More likely you will need to specify that in your InstallShield project.

Comment: Thanks for your concern Sir. Can you tell me the other solution which you think (you have used yourself for this sort of application deployment) is a good alternative to this one?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the specific dataBase manager, it deppens of the version of your ms access file
these some connection string for oledb ,you can use also odbc
2003 : Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\myDb;
Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;

> 2007 : Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
>   Persist Security Info=False;

Comment: I can't give absolute path to my database file. This will give error on user's machine. Please provide more information or any tutorial if you can.

Comment: You can generate absolute path on user machine and use it as `Data Source`. What is the problem? [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.datasource.aspx) is an example.

Comment: What if the shortcut will be created at user's machine? Would my database respond the same as it does now before deployment? My databse file is in bin folder right now.